# Keepalive : add new node to a former cluster

Tags: keep-alive, ubuntu-server

I have a question about a cluster we have in production.

It contains 2 nodes, one master and a slave, with this version :
Keepalived v1.2.7 (08/14,2013)

The new node we want to add is based on this version :
Keepalived v1.3.9 (10/21,2017)

Do you know if I can, and how I can, push this new node into my old cluster, without interruptions ?

This is the configuration file of the old cluster :

```
global_defs {
    lvs_id cluster
}

vrrp_script check_nginx {
    script "killall -0 nginx"
    interval 1
    weight 2
}

vrrp_instance cluster {
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 1

    state MASTER
    priority 101
    advert_int 1

    authentication {
        auth_type PASS
        auth_pass **********
    }

    vrrp_unicast_bind 10.xx.xx.xx
    vrrp_unicast_peer 10.xx.xx.xx

    virtual_ipaddress {
        10.xx.xx.xx # First node
        10.xx.xx.xx # Second node
    }

    track_script {
        check_nginx
    }
}
```

I don't know if it's possible and I don't want to crash the cluster trying some moves.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like impossible to share two configurations between these versions.
We forgot this idea.